# How to get XML/JSON data for api.drupal.org?

Tags: 7, community-official-site

In my earlier question [How to get node IDs from drupal.org?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/154435/how-to-get-node-ids-from-drupal-org), I can get the XML data of a node by going to https://www.drupal.org/api-d7/node/274365.xml where 274365 is the node id of a particular page. In similar way I can access all the node in **drupal.org** Website.

Now I want the same kind of **XML data** for a node pages in https://api.drupal.org.

For example what is the XML data page for https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/group/hooks/7 ?

Answer (score 1):

I was curious about this, too. Below is a dump of the API in JSON format. Unfortunately I don't think the same is available in XML format, or that the query can be further refined to, say, retrieve only a list of hooks.

URL structure:

```
api/(project)/full_list/(branch)?limit=M&page=N
```

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/full_list/7?limit=20&page=0

#### Source

- [Public API into api.drupal.org? Or at least simplified redirects?](https://www.drupal.org/node/2369135)